# Java Look and Feel Class UI pointing to wrong class

Tags: java, look-and-feel

I am trying to make my own look and feel at the moment, but when I try creating any of the UIs it points to the wrong location.

When I try to add this to the UIDefaults:

```
    import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI;

    public class TreeUI extends BasicTreeUI{

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Test run!";
        }

    }
```

Then the JTree object I create gets BasicTreeUI object. But the odd thing is that if I try to use this:

```
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalTreeUI;

public class TreeUI extends MetalTreeUI {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test run!";
    }

}
```

The JTree gets a MetalTreeUI object instead. This is independent of any other changes. And in both cases toString does not override.

How do I correctly implement a TreeUI that uses the TreeUI object for JTrees?

Caller for reference (class extends MetalLookAndFeel):

```
@Override
protected void initClassDefaults(UIDefaults table) {
    super.initClassDefaults(table);
    table.put("TreeUI", "someCorrectPath.TreeUI");
}
```

Edit: When I try putting TreeUI in a wrapper, it still defaults to either MetalTreeUI or BasicTreeUI instead of just getting whatever it is currently extending.